# What is the reason that my GWT application still using old .jasper (compiled templates) instead of using new ones

Tags: java, gwt, jasper-reports, ireport

I have created a report using *iReport*. Then I compile it using *iReport* compilation button to generate *.jasper* file. In order to use it in *GWT* application, I added *.jasper* file under war folder in *GWT* application. First time it works fine, but when I edit report in *iReport* and recompile it then it replaced old version of *.jasper* file with new compiled version. 
Old version still works, not new version, what is reason of that?

Comment: Did you try to restart application? Did you clean the cache?

Answer (score 2):

Check the file permission. Sometimes you see the change in the iReport but it will not be saved if you don't have the write permission on the jrxml. If you are using some version control, check out the file and then try editing it.

Comment: this maybe if changes doesn't reflect in any way , but situation happened that show new Compiled report correctly first time opened in GWT application , but when try to open report another time later , it return back to old compiled report ... for example , yesterday i did some edits on report at iReport and compile it , then load .Jasper file in my GWT application and try it , report opened new compiled correctly , but when try to open it today at morning , returns back to old compiled version ... this is the situation happened with me

Comment: Where do you store the files? Is the Save Button enabled in iReport when you start modifying the template? iReport can compile the template and produce the jasper file without saving your latest changes to the jrxml file. We were facing the same issue. But it stopped occuring when we started modifying the template only after checking it out in clearcase.